# Eclipse plugins in hadoop on windows

Tags: hadoop

I'm new to the hadoop.I am trying to install hadoop on my windows machine with the help of following link i.e. http://blog.v-lad.org/archives/4#comment-43

I'm using eclipse IDE:3.3.1
            javaJDK    :1.6.0_24
            Hadoop     :0.21.0
Everything fine, eclipse IDE when i select the "new hadoop location" action is not perform.I didn't get the problem .Any one can help me

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the eclipse-plugin to the installation directory of eclipse?

`...\hadoop-0.21.0\mapred\contrib\eclipse-plugin\hadoop-0.21.0-eclipse-plugin.jar`

to

`...\eclipse\dropins`

P.S. the eclipse-plugin of Hadoop :0.21.0 is not complete.

You can download the revised one at http://www.lifeba.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/hadoop-0.21.0-eclipse-plugin-3.6.rar

Although it's for eclipse 3.6 ,I suppose it's also compatible for eclipse 3.3.1

——————————————————————————————

Oh, I just noticed the time...years ago... sorry

I hope it be useful for those who encountered this problem recently.